# Rotating a line according to BPM and Beats per Measure

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a drum machine based on a circle and need a radar-like line to rotate at a speed modulated by the tempo, with a period equal to the beats per measure. This way it rotates at speed, and completes a revolution at the equivalent duration of one measure.

I'm having a hard time modeling this algebraically. From what I've figured out:

seconds per  beat = 60secs/bpm

```
 60secs/120bpm = .5spb
```

Spb * bbpm (beats per measure) yields spm (seconds per measure).

```
 .5bps * 4bbpm = 2spm
```

This is where I'm stuck. I know that in 2 seconds the line needs to have turned 360 degrees in order to complete a four beat measure. I'm having a hard time modelling this much less committing it to code.

What I've started to guess at is to divide the framerate by the spm to yield frames per second per measure. However I've tried to divide that by 360 to determine the amount of degrees per frame per second per measure but when compared to a true metronome my tick arm is inaccurate.

Any insights would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math

SIZE = 800, 800
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
framerate = 40
done = False
bpm = int(input("Enter a BPM: ")) #beats per minute
bbpm = int(input("How many Beats Per Measure?: ")) #beats per measure
spb = (60/bpm)
spm = spb*bbpm #speed per measure; a measure is made every x seconds
frames = (framerate/spm) 
rev = 360/frames # degrees per frame
deg = 0
secs = 0

while not done:
    screen.fill(0)
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT or (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
            done = True
            break

    line = (400,400)
    line_len = 400
    x = line[0] + math.cos(math.radians(deg)) * line_len
    y = line[1] + math.sin(math.radians(deg)) * line_len

    # then render the line ->(x,y)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, Color("red"), line, (x,y), 1)
    pygame.display.flip()
    print(secs)
    print(deg)
    deg+=rev
    secs+= 1
    clock.tick(framerate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In motion rendering, never rely on hard-coded framerate or any constant speed per frame. Measure time delta since some reference position (e.g. in this case since last turn or init) and calculate current position according to the time delta. Even with vsync on you may miss some frames and framerate does not always equal to 60.

2) Don't sync rendering with delays based on supposed framerate, use instead hardware vsync (in this case using `pygame.display.set_mode(..., pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)`)

Your measure caclulation seems correct. There is no need in degrees to convert revolutions to radians.

Corrected example:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math

SIZE = 800, 800
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
done = False
bpm = 120# int(input("Enter a BPM: ")) #beats per minute
bbpm = 4# int(input("How many Beats Per Measure?: ")) #beats per measure
spm = bbpm*60/bpm #seconds per measure; a measure is made every x seconds
turnsPerMs = 1/(1000*spm) #turns per millisecond
startTime = pygame.time.get_ticks()
color = Color("red")
lineStart = (400,400)
line_len = 400

while not done:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT or (e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE):
            done = True
            break   

    screen.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, lineStart, line_len, 2)

    timeDelta = pygame.time.get_ticks() - startTime
    revDelta = timeDelta*turnsPerMs;
    deltaRadian = revDelta*2*math.pi;
    x = lineStart[0] + math.cos(deltaRadian) * line_len
    y = lineStart[1] + math.sin(deltaRadian) * line_len

    # then render the line ->(x,y)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color, lineStart, (x,y), 1)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand using time delta to effect motion. I think I understand that you multiplied revDelta by 2pi to get a value in radians (deltaRadian). Im trying to understand currently the revDelta variable. The change in time from the beginning of the calculation to the current moment multiplied by the amount of turns in a millisecond. That gives you how many turns the arm should make over the elapsed time period, correct? And then deltaRadians just converts that value into radians. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yep. Very simple: for linear motion `distance=speed*time` (for angle`=angular speed*time`). So, we just calculate angular speed before loop and in loop multiply passed time by the speed to get resulting angle. For the sake of example clarity, I defined angular speed in turns/ms and before angle calculation I've converted it to radian. In fact, you can precalculate straight in radian, instead of revPerMs: `radPerMs = (2*math.pi)(/1000*spm)`, then (distance) angle in radian inside loop will be `radDelta=radPerMs*timeDelta` and `x = ..cos(radDelta)..`